# Firestore security rules passing wildcard variable to path

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have the following security rules:

```
    match /collection1/{doc_id} {
      allow read: if (get(/databases/$(database)/documents/collection2/$(doc_id)).author == 
                  request.auth.uid);
    }
```

What I am doing is that I am trying to pass the wildcard variable from the parent path `doc_id` into the path of `get` method. The read access of this doc in `collection1` depends on the `author` field of a document with the same id in another collection `collection2`. I don't believe that the way I am passing `doc_id` as `$(doc_id)` is correct, as I get an error of: `Property author is undefined on object`

I have also tried `(doc_id)` and `\doc_id`, but they are syntaxilly wrong. How do I pass a wildcard variable to a path then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a `data` in there, which is needed to get at the fields of the document:

```
get(/databases/$(database)/documents/collection2/$(doc_id)).data.author
```

Comment: Ah, `get(path) returns rules.firestore.Resource` I forgot `data`. Thanks Frank